# recorded audio distorted in safari 11 when using visualization with web rtc

Tags: safari, webrtc, recordrtc

I've created a demo to show this, it seems that when I show a visualization the recorded audio gets really crunchy. Is there any way I can fix this? This works in chrome and Firefox, but safari is the only offender.

```
<style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0!important;
        padding: 0!important;
        overflow: hidden!important;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<title>Audio Recording | RecordRTC</title>
<h1>Simple Audio Recording using RecordRTC</h1>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

<br>

<button id="btn-start-recording">Start Recording</button>
<button id="btn-stop-recording" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
<label><input id="visualizer" type="checkbox" checked/>Show Visualizer</label>

<hr>
<canvas id="audio-canvas"></canvas>
<div><audio controls autoplay></audio></div>

<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>

<script>
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');

function captureMicrophone(callback) {

    if(microphone) {
        callback(microphone);
        return;
    }

    if(typeof navigator.mediaDevices === 'undefined' || !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        alert('This browser does not supports WebRTC getUserMedia API.');

        if(!!navigator.getUserMedia) {
            alert('This browser seems supporting deprecated getUserMedia API.');
        }
    }

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: {
            echoCancellation: false
        }
    }).then(function(mic) {
        callback(mic);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert('Unable to capture your microphone. Please check console logs.');
        console.error(error);
    });
}

function replaceAudio(src) {
    var newAudio = document.createElement('audio');
    newAudio.controls = true;

    if(src) {
        newAudio.src = src;
    }

    var parentNode = audio.parentNode;
    parentNode.innerHTML = '';
    parentNode.appendChild(newAudio);

    audio = newAudio;
}

function stopRecordingCallback() {
    replaceAudio(URL.createObjectURL(recorder.getBlob()));

    btnStartRecording.disabled = false;

    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!audio.paused) return;

        setTimeout(function() {
            if(!audio.paused) return;
            audio.play();
        }, 1000);

        audio.play();
    }, 300);

    audio.play();

    if(microphone) {
        microphone.stop();
        microphone = null;
    }
}

var recorder; // globally accessible
var microphone;

var btnStartRecording = document.getElementById('btn-start-recording');
var btnStopRecording = document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording');
var canvas = document.getElementById('audio-canvas');
var visualizerCheckbox = document.getElementById('visualizer'); 

btnStartRecording.onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    this.style.border = '';
    this.style.fontSize = '';

    if (!microphone) {
        captureMicrophone(function(mic) {
            microphone = mic;

            replaceAudio();

            audio.muted = true;
            audio.play();

            btnStartRecording.disabled = false;
            btnStartRecording.style.border = '1px solid red';
            btnStartRecording.style.fontSize = '150%';

            alert('Please click startRecording button again. First time we tried to access your microphone. Now we will record it.');
        });
        return;
    }

    replaceAudio();

    audio.muted = true;
    audio.play();

    if(visualizerCheckbox.checked){
        initScope(canvas);
    }

    var options = {
        type: 'audio',
        numberOfAudioChannels: 2,
        checkForInactiveTracks: true,
        bufferSize: 16384,
        sampleRate: 48000
    };

    if(recorder) {
        recorder.destroy();
        recorder = null;
    }

    recorder = RecordRTC(microphone, options);

    recorder.startRecording();

    btnStopRecording.disabled = false;
};

btnStopRecording.onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    recorder.stopRecording(stopRecordingCallback);
};

function initScope(audioScopeCanvas) {
        if (audioScopeCanvas) {
            var analyser;
            var mic;
            var javascriptNode;
            var canvasContext;
            audioContext = new AudioContext(); // NEW!!
            analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
            mic = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(microphone);
            javascriptNode =  audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);

            analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
            analyser.fftSize = 1024;

            mic.connect(analyser);
            analyser.connect(javascriptNode);
            javascriptNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

            //canvasContext = $("#canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
            canvasContext = audioScopeCanvas.getContext("2d");

            javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function () {
                var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
                analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
                var values = 0;

                var length = array.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    values += array[i];
                }

                var average = values / length;
                canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 60, 130);
                canvasContext.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
                canvasContext.fillRect(0, 130 - average, 25, 130);
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

you can play with it here:
[Http://andrew.colchagoff.com/safari-record.html](http://andrew.colchagoff.com/safari-record)

I'm using record rtc.

Comment: I am having the same problem (now w/Safari 12). Have you had any breakthroughs?

Comment: not really, I ended up disabling the visualization in safari via user agents and safari users just see red text that says 'recording'

Comment: I can not figure out the correct options for Safari. I am getting distorted audio. Chrome and FF are fine. For Safari I use these options. I've tried variations of this with 1 or 2 channels. Do you recall what options you used for Safari?

```const options = {
      type: 'audio',
      mimeType: 'audio/wav',
      recorderType: RecordRTC.StereoAudioRecorder,
      numberOfAudioChannels: 1,
      checkForInactiveTracks: true,
      sampleRate: 44100,
      bufferSize: 4096
    };```

Comment: I don't really remember, but you're welcome to view the source of my example.